# Why do these 2 queries return different results from the Oracle hr database?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
select J.job_title,
       D.department_name,
       E.first_name || ' ' || E.last_name as "Employee Name",
       H.start_date
from   job_history H
       join jobs J
       on H.job_id = J.job_id
       join departments D
       on H.department_id = D.department_id
       join employees E
       on H.department_id = E.department_id
where  H.start_date between '01-Jan-93' and '03-Aug-97';
```

2nd query

```sql
SELECT job_title,
       department_name,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS Employee_name,
       start_date 
FROM   job_history
       JOIN jobs USING (job_id) 
       JOIN departments USING (department_id) 
       JOIN  employees USING (employee_id) 
WHERE  start_date between '01-jan-93' AND '08-aug-97';
```

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. I used the wrong column names when joining the employees table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different answers (more rows from the first query, which is very likely the wrong query) because in the first query you join the last table, `employees`, to the first table, `job_history`, on the `department_id` column. (In the second query you join by `employee_id`, which is probably the correct way.)

This way, for every row in `job_history` that matches and employee in the `employees` table **on the `department_id` column** you will get a row in the join output - even if the employee doesn't match that `job_history` row by employee id. **All** employees in the `Executive` department will appear in the output.

Note that your `where` clause is not the same (one period ends 3 August, the other 8 August), but that is **not** the reason for the different output. (It might be on different data though.)

Also, they should teach you not to use strings in date comparisons; but this is unrelated to your question.